# Paypal MassPay api get data from IPN

Tags: php, paypal, masspay

I am using papyal MassPay api to send payment. While sending payment paypal not returning payment status and transaction ID as well. The only way to get details is from IPN. But i am stuck with the IPN. I am not getting how i can check each transaction and its status from IPN.

```
Results: Array
(
    [payer_id] => HDG123
    [payment_date] => 02:56:22 Oct 05, 2017 PDT
    [payment_gross_1] =>
    [payment_gross_2] =>
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [receiver_email_1] => test1@gmail.com
    [receiver_email_2] => test2@gmail.com
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [mc_currency_1] => CAD
    [masspay_txn_id_1] => 9DY72188PA481234
    [mc_currency_2] => CAD
    [masspay_txn_id_2] => 6U883047ND871234
    [first_name] => Hardik
    [unique_id_1] => 123719736059d601b0d1cda
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [unique_id_2] => 2130719736059d601b0d1dbf
    [payer_status] => verified
    [status_1] => Completed
    [status_2] => Completed
    [txn_type] => masspay
    [mc_gross_1] => 82.86
    [mc_gross_2] => 102.90
    [payment_fee_1] =>
    [residence_country] => CA
    [payment_fee_2] =>
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [mc_fee_1] => 1.25
    [mc_fee_2] => 1.25
    [ipn_track_id] => c85ffe2791234
)
```